# How to pass params in VUE PWA app in order to fetch different data?

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps

I am developing VUE PWA (with VUE-CLI) and I need to fetch different data depending on provided params. Let me explain what I need, I have `http://localhost:8080/proconnect/` (I changed `publicPath: '/proconnect/'` in my `vue.config.js` and it works fine, but I need to grab different data from API depending on param. I try to use simple GET params like this `http://localhost:8080/proconnect/?code=123`, this works fine in a browser, but when I install PWA on my computer as an app it loads without GET param.

I use PHP for the backend. The app works fine when it built on the server.

I need to pass param somehow to my app to fetch different data. I don't mind to use different subdomains or another way to solve this issue. I will appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `vue-router`, a simple way to get the params is by using the `useRoute` hook. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html#accessing-the-router-and-current-route-inside-setup

Comment: params are not passed if you open PWA on your device after installation